# Implement fade into script

Tags: jquery, fadein

Last time I did code was 6 years ago so I forgot a lot unfortunately.
I can't figure out how to implement the fade property into this script.

The slideshow is working but i want the images to fadeIn instead of pop in.

```
var picPaths = ['images/home1.png', 'images/home2.png', 'images/home3.png', 'images/home4.png'];
var curPic = -1;
//preload the images for smooth animation
var imgO = new Array();
for (i = 0; i < picPaths.length; i++) {
    imgO[i] = new Image();
    imgO[i].src = picPaths[i];
}

function swapImage() {
    curPic = (++curPic > picPaths.length - 1) ? 0 : curPic;
    imgCont.src = imgO[curPic].src;
    setTimeout(swapImage, 3500);
}

window.onload = function () {
    imgCont = document.getElementById('content1');
    swapImage();
}
```

If anyone could tell me where to put it and if you have the time why.., I would be very gratefull.

If you need more information please ask.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming imgCont is a global variable then in `swapImage` I would call

```
imgCont.fadeOut();
```

then set the new image

```
imgCont.src = imgO[curPic].src;
```

then fade in

```
imgCont.fadeIn();
```

I made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p6f8msb5/) to show the correct use as the subsequent lines have to go in a function inside the fade out so that the fade completes before the image swaps, and then the fade in completes before triggering the timeout call.

UPDATE:

you will need an include of jquery on your page somewhere (for example this link to the online cdn for jquery):

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
```

so re-writing your original code using jquery and the fiddle code,

in HTML

```
<img id="img_on_page" src="http://www.degraafschilderwerk.nl/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/houtsanering3.jpg"/>
```

in `<script>`

```
var picPaths = ['images/home1.png', 'images/home2.png', 'images/home3.png', 'images/home4.png'];
var currentPicIndex = 0;

$(function(){
   //this is the 'page load ready' function
   swapImage(); //this starts the swapping..
});

function swapImage(){
    $("#img_on_page").fadeOut(function(){
        //this code happens AFTER the fadeOut animation is done.
        currentPicIndex++;
        if( currentPicIndex > picPaths.length-1) currentPicIndex = 0; //loop images back to start when end of array reached.
        $("#img_on_page").prop("src", a[swap]);    
        $("#img_on_page").fadeIn(function(){
            //this code happens AFTER the fadeIn animation is done.
            setTimeout(swapImage, 2000);
        });
    });

}
```

I also created an updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p6f8msb5/8/) with this code.

Comment: Thank you for your reaction.

Comment: If my answer helped solve your issue then upvote and accept the answer (tick icon).

Comment: I will off course!! for now i'm still figuring out why i'm stupid and don't get it to work. ^^

Comment: where are you stuck? Did you look at the JSFiddle I made?

Comment: When i put in the code from fiddle, it just give me blanks. If i mess up the image path in fiddle, the broken image show top left but appears to be changing. In my own work nothing happens. btw I tried to write it myself first, not stealing your work! :) I appreciate the time and effort!!

Comment: ok where are you defining imgCont, and additionally you will need to change the line in your onload method to make imgCont a jquery object. So swap the document.getelementbyid to $("#content1");

Comment: Late response had to out for a job interview... but stil I don't get it, https://jsfiddle.net/p6f8msb5/2/ this seems to work in fiddle but when i put the same code into a html page it doesn't change or move... any suggestions on why?

Comment: starting with the basics, are you including jquery on the page?

Comment: If you mean: <script>code</script> then yes. When it works i will include the script like <script src="jq/myscript.js"></script>

Comment: ok, I'm going to re-write the code you initially provided using jquery and the excerpt from the fiddle. (Your original code didn't use any jquery, just vanilla javascript). Your jquery include should look like, <script src="link_to jquery.js_file"></script>. That include is not the js file that contains your code.

Comment: ok re-write done and my answer is updated with code and a new fiddle. Let me know if you can get it to work!